# How do I change the font size in Dwarf-fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, linux

I'm trying of DF 0.34.11 (linux) and was wondering if it's possible to increase the font size. I've looked through the forum without any luck (so far).

Comment: Your best bet would be to install and activate a graphical tileset. Can't access DF from where I am; I'll elaborate if it hasn't been answered by the time I can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options: zoom in or use a larger font (or tileset).

To zoom, you can use the mousewheel or the [ and ] keys to zoom in and out, which is good for quickly getting a close up look at something or a quick overview of your domain. It does tend to make things blurry, though. The `ZOOM_SPEED` setting affects how fast it zooms.

To use a different font, you'll have to edit `data/init/init.txt` (which is also where you find `ZOOM_SPEED`). There are a lot of settings here, most of them well documented in the file itself, but the ones you're interested in are `FONT`, `GRAPHICS_FONT`, and `GRAPHICS_FULLFONT`, which control the font in non-tiled, tiled windowed, and tiled fullscreen modes.

The default font is `curses_640x300`, which is intended for use in an 80x24 tile game window at 640x300 resolution (hence the name), so the tiles are pretty small - 8x12. `curses_square_16x16` is a better choice; the tiles are square, and noticeably larger. If you want something different (or larger still), you can download a wide variety of fonts and tilesets from [the wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Tilesets).

Answer (score 1):

Changing `PRINT_MODE` to `TEXT` in your `data/init/init.txt` might help: the game is then rendered with the font you have selected in your terminal.